# XNA Parallaxing background wont show all the layers

Tags: c#, xna, camera, 2d, parallax

Im playing around with the Platformer Starter Kit and so far I've added in horizontal and vertical "camera" movement and Im trying to add inn a parallaxing background. The problem is that after two background layers it stops showing the rest of them. Im very new to XNA and need a little help :). Heres a pic of the problem:

[image: layer fail]

Heres the code. Please tell me if you need some more :)

Layer classes:

```
class Layer
 {
    public Texture2D[] Textures { get; private set; }
    public float ScrollRate { get; private set; }

    public Layer(ContentManager content, string basePath, float scrollRate)
    {
        // Assumes each layer only has 3 segments.
        Textures = new Texture2D[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            Textures[i] = content.Load<Texture2D>(basePath + "_" + i);

        ScrollRate = scrollRate;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, float cameraPosition, float cameraPositionYAxis)
    {
        // Assume each segment is the same width.
        int segmentWidth = Textures[0].Width;

        // Calculate which segments to draw and how much to offset them.
        float x = cameraPosition * ScrollRate;
        float y = ScrollRate;
        int leftSegment = (int)Math.Floor(x / segmentWidth);
        int rightSegment = leftSegment + 1;
        x = (x / segmentWidth - leftSegment) * -segmentWidth;

        spriteBatch.Draw(Textures[leftSegment % Textures.Length], new Vector2(x, -y), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(Textures[rightSegment % Textures.Length], new Vector2(x + segmentWidth, -y), Color.White);
    }


}
```

Heres the draw method in my Level.cs with my ScrollCamera (dont know if ScrollCamera has anything to do with it)

```
public void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        ScrollCamera(spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice.Viewport);
        Matrix cameraTransformYAxis = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-cameraPosition, -cameraPositionYAxis, 0.0f);
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearClamp,
            DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise, null, cameraTransformYAxis);

        //added this foreach loop 
        foreach (var layer in layers)
        {
            layer.Draw(spriteBatch, cameraPosition, cameraPositionYAxis);
        }

        DrawTiles(spriteBatch);
        Player.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
        foreach (Enemy enemy in enemies)
        {
            enemy.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
        }

        spriteBatch.End();

    }

    private void ScrollCamera(Viewport viewport)
    {
        #if ZUNE
        const float ViewMargin = 0.4f;
        #else
        const float ViewMargin = 0.5f;
        #endif

        float marginWidth = viewport.Width * ViewMargin;
        float marginLeft = cameraPosition + marginWidth;
        float marginRight = cameraPosition + viewport.Width - marginWidth;


        const float TopMargin = 0.4f;
        const float BottomMargin = 0.4f;
        float marginTop = cameraPositionYAxis + viewport.Height * TopMargin;
        float marginBottom = cameraPositionYAxis + viewport.Height - viewport.Height * BottomMargin;
        //    float maxCameraPositionYOffset = Tile.Height * Height - viewport.Height; 


        float CameraMovement = 0.0f;
        if (Player.Position.X < marginLeft)
            CameraMovement = Player.Position.X - marginLeft;
        else if (Player.Position.X > marginRight)
            CameraMovement = Player.Position.X - marginRight;
        //Aktualizuj przesuwanie ekranu, ale zapobiegnij wyjściu poza mape
        float maxCameraPosition = Tile.Width * Width - viewport.Width;
        cameraPosition = MathHelper.Clamp(cameraPosition + CameraMovement, 0.0f, maxCameraPosition);



        float cameraMovementY = 0.0f;
        if (Player.Position.Y < marginTop) //above the top margin
            cameraMovementY = Player.Position.Y - marginTop;
        else if (Player.Position.Y > marginBottom) //below the bottom margin
            cameraMovementY = Player.Position.Y - marginBottom;

        float maxCameraPositionYOffset = Tile.Height * Height - viewport.Height;
        cameraPositionYAxis = MathHelper.Clamp(cameraPositionYAxis + cameraMovementY, 0.0f, maxCameraPositionYOffset);

    }
```

And I think thats it. Please tell me if you need some more code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use Linear Wrapping. [There's an excellent blog post on it right here.](http://www.david-gouveia.com/scrolling-textures-in-xna/) This assumes of course that your texture tiles perfect. You just simply need to to set your linear wrapping mode, code example below:

```
// Use this one instead!
spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, null, SamplerState.LinearWrap, null, null);
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, new Rectangle(-scrollX, -scrollY, texture.Width, texture.Height), Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();
```

Comment: Thanks you for answering and this looks pretty simple, but Im not really sure on how to insert this into my project and I couldnt quite figure out on how to insert this into my project. Is it as simple as I just put it in my draw method and everything works :P ?

Comment: When you draw your tiling, just set the SpriteBatch begin call as I have and draw like normal. Keep in mind, only do this for the tiled stuff. You'll need to start a new batch for everything you don't want wrapped. Other than that, yes. It's automatic.

Comment: I still cant figure it out.
Do I do this in my Draw method in the level.cs or somewhere else? and exactly how? sorry If Im asking stupid questions. :P

Comment: You need to find where you call spriteBatch begin for your tiling calls.

Comment: Is that the spriteBatch.Begin(); in my level.cs?

Comment: Yeah, it is. Just apply that to the batch.

Comment: hmmm... didnt seem to quite work. It still didnt show all of my background layer pics and the "camera" stopped following my sprite around. here are some pics to show you what I meant. http://i.imgur.com/HXXd7gk.png  and this where my camera didnt follow the sprite but the tiles only loaded when it was around http://i.imgur.com/uexa5RH.png

Comment: I found out what was wrong. I just forgot to add another integer and then draw it. It was as simple as that. :) silly me

Comment: Sounds like you're just repeating the texture - this isn't the proper way to do it, unfortunately. :(